# Adding a new subscriber to a Mailchimp audience using Java and a Jersey Client

Tags: java, post, jersey-client, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I need to add a subscriber to a mailchimp audience. I am using Java and a Jersey client. I have no trouble fetching the members of the audience using the Mailchimp 3.0 API. What must I change about my post request in order to successfully add a new subscriber? When my code fails, there is no response. Then, when I check the Mailchimp account and see that no new subscriber was added.

```
class MailchimpClient {

    Client client;
    String mailchimpUrl;

    public MailchimpClient() {
        String mailchimpApikey = getAPIKey();
        String datacenter = mailchimpApikey.substring(mailchimpApikey.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
        mailchimpUrl = "https://" + datacenter + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/";

        JacksonJsonProvider jjp = new JacksonJsonProvider();
        jjp.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        ClientConfig conf = new ClientConfig();
        conf.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TIMEOUT);
        conf.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, TIMEOUT);
        conf.register(jjp);

        HttpAuthenticationFeature httpAuth = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("username", mailchimpApikey);

        client = ClientBuilder.newClient(conf).register(httpAuth);
    }

    public <T> T get(String path, Class<T> responseType) {
        T t = client.target(mailchimpUrl).path(path).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
        client.close();
        return t;
    }

    public <T> T post(String path, Object payload, Class<T> responseType) {
        Entity<Object> entity = Entity.entity(payload, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        T t = client.target(mailchimpUrl).path(path).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(entity, responseType);
        client.close();
        return t;
    }
```

```
    String audienceid = xxxxxxx;
    MailchimpClient mcc = new MailchimpClient();
    MembersResponse mr = mcc.get("lists/" + audienceid + "/members", MembersResponse.class);
    addToMailchimpAudience(String audienceid);
```

```
private Message addToMailchimpAudience(String audienceid) {
    HashMap<String, String> newMember = new HashMap<String, String>();
    newMember.put("email_address", "bob@gmail.com");
    newMember.put("status", "subscribed");
    MailchimpClient mcc = new MailchimpClient();
    MembersResponse mr = mcc.post("lists/" + audienceid + "/members", newMember, MembersResponse.class);
    logger.info("response: " + mr);
    return Message.success("Successfully added new member to mailchimp audience");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The request to add new members should be a JSON
Add a Contact to a List/Audience

To add a contact to a list/audience, send a POST request to the List Members endpoint: /3.0/lists/9e67587f52/members/. The request body should be a JSON object that contains the information you want to add, with status and any other required list fields.

{
"email_address": "urist.mcvankab@freddiesjokes.com",
"status": "subscribed",
"merge_fields": {
"FNAME": "Urist",
"LNAME": "McVankab"
}
}

I observed you are sending values in a HasMap, trying converting into a JSON and see if it works

Link for your reference:
https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/